# What Error type to use for empty objects in python ie... empty linked list

Tags: python, data-structures

I was wondering about the error type I would raise if a call were made to a delete method for my linked list, and the linked list was empty.

I couldn't find any documentation on what particular error type to raise.

Would `ValueError` work for this purpose or is there some other error type?

Comment: An `IndexError` would be a reasonable one.

Comment: Use the same exception as you do when the requested item isn't found. You can use `list.remove()` as a model.

Comment: What is the parameter to this method? Is it a list position or a list value?

Comment: @Barmar It is a simple integer, oh and I used the Value error for when the item isn't found

Comment: But what role does that integer play? Is it an index or value?

Comment: @Barmar it is a value

Comment: Then `ValueError` seems like the obvious choice, assuming you also raise that exception if it can't be found in a non-empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if you attempt an operation on an object that is generally valid, but can't work for the specific object you called it on (or with a specific argument) due to its value, a `ValueError` exception is appropriate.

For example, the `list.remove` method uses this error type if the requested value can't be found after searching the list (which will certainly be the case if the list is empty).

If your delete method lets the user choose which node to remove based on position within the list (rather than its value), an `IndexError` might be another reasonable choice. That is the exception type raised by the `list.pop` method if it fails to find anything to remove and return.

Or if your list behaves like a mapping between a key and a value, a `KeyError` would be appropriate to indicate that a given key couldn't be found. Even if you don't supply a key, methods like `dict.popitem` will use `KeyError` for consistency with other methods, like `dict.pop`, where you do.